# Drive to store very small amount of data

Tags: data-storage

I am currently designing a board game whereby various cards, figurines, and basically all sorts of game items will be plugged into the main game board, which will be linked to a Raspberry Pi.

As various items can be plugged into the same socket, I would like some data to be stored in each item, so that the main program loop can respond accordingly.

This data would be very small: only a few bytes.

What would be the best hardware to use as storage on the game items? USB drives would work well in terms of plugging in, however they seem a bit overkill in terms of storage size.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Would NFC chips work?

Comment: They would be ideal in terms of purpose however because I require a vast amount of ports in close proximity I imagine they would quickly become problematic. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: OK, what about QR codes?

Comment: Also fits the bill quite well if only for the prohibitive cost and size of physical QR scanners

Comment: Well that's because of the design of your board rather than the storage tech :p if you used a pi with a web cam gazing down at the board from a slight isometric angle, you could cheaply accomplish your goals by having it recognize the qr codes printed on top of each unit base!

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is an argument to be made here:  Which is more important, low cost, or low capacity?   I would suggest this:  [THZY 512M USB](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIABR04J41811)

Simply based on low price this would work.

Capacity is 512MB, so not overboard.